# Error when doing a SQL Server query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am doing this query in a stored procedure: `SELECT TOP 1 [Employe] FROM Transactions WHERE [Employe]=@Name AND Date=@Date`

It is supposed to return an employee ID (int). In my application (ASP.NET C#) I get this error when, with a DataReader, I read a line:
*Conversion failed when converting the varchar value * to data type int. *

What exactly is the type * ? And I am not trying to convert anything.

Comment: I'd like to see more code, please. The procedure's code, and also how you're executing the DataReader. Is `Employe` spelled right?

Comment: Typically that error shows the data contained in the varchar value that is being used.  In this case, somewhere it thinks a * is present.  We may need more code and what's in the database to properly help with that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are passing `@Name` parameter as a `varchar` where `Employe` field is an `int` field.

Or you could be trying to assign your resulting value of `Employe` to an `int` datatype then you would be seeing this error.

Please post your `Transactions` table definition and your stored procedure code to further troubleshoot.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're sleecting the `Employe` column which I'm guessing is `varchar`. I'm assuming you want to select the `ID` column.

```
SELECT TOP 1 [ID] FROM Transactions WHERE [Employe]=@Name AND Date=@Date
```

Comment: He may also want to do WHERE [Employe] LIKE Name and not = Name, since it also looks like Name contains a '*'

Answer (score 0):

I think probably your `@Name` parameter is specified as an `VARCHAR`, but the Employe field in the table is an `INT` field.

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Employe] FROM Transactions WHERE CAST([Employe] AS VARCHAR)=@Name AND Date=@Date
```

Comment: Thanks for all your answers!

Just figured out what my error was: I declared my @Name parameter as a varchar in my stored procedure and entered a int I my C# code. N00b error, I know!